# Node command not found when bash script is run through desktop icon

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to run a node app from a desktop icon using a bash script. The desktop icon executes the bash script and this one is supposed to run the node app. If I run the bash script manually, node app is launched normally, but when I do double click on the desktop icon, then the bash script returns: `line 3 node: command not found` and it finish with Bye (see the script below).

Here the `.desktop` icon content and the bash script.

the .desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Todo
Comment=Shortcut to my app
Exec='/home/myuser/app/run_todo.sh'
Icon=/home/myuser/Pictures/donatello.svg
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application
```

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/myuser/app/todo_app/
node ./app.js
echo "Bye"
$SHELL
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and Node 12.14.1 installed through nvm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workmate solved the problem. Just add

`PATH="/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin:$PATH"`

after the `#!/bin/bash` line.

So the bash script is finally:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="/home/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v12.14.1/bin:$PATH"

cd /home/myuser/app/todo_app/
node ./app.js
echo "Bye"
$SHELL
```